# Setting expires on asp cookies with keys won't work

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

I have a login page written in classic asp. I want to set the users login information into asp cookies so the next time they arrive at the page they stay logged in for a period of 2 weeks.

The problem is when I set an expiry on the cookie which contains keys the cookies don't persit when the browser is closed.

Here is an example of my code:

```
response.cookies("user")("userId")=userId
response.cookies("user")("firstName")=firstName
response.cookies("user")("lastName")=lastName
response.cookies("user").expires=dateadd("d",14,now)
```

Setting a cookie without keys works, but when using keys expires doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work... just move the expiration to be the first value you set for the key:

```
response.cookies("user").expires=dateadd("D",14,Date())
response.cookies("user")("userId") = userId
response.cookies("user")("firstName") = firstName
response.cookies("user")("lastName") = lastName
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, the cookies are still lost when the browser closes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of msigman works fine. Tested it on my local server. Cookie still present when closing and opening the browser again.

Maybe add the (sub)domain name?

```
response.cookies("user").domain="example.com"
response.cookies("user").expires=dateadd("D",14,Date())
response.cookies("user")("userId") = userId
response.cookies("user")("firstName") = firstName
response.cookies("user")("lastName") = lastName
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working for me, would it be something set on the server, I'm using IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: Are cookies enabled for the site? And are cookies enabled in your browser? It is pretty basic code, so I agree the problem might be in the server software.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your IIS panel?  I wonder if you have a setting that is expiring the cookies for you ?  Another thing is perhaps try hard coding the expire and test it just to see if it also fails?

```
response.cookies("user").expires=#May 30,2021#
response.cookies("user")("userId") = userId
response.cookies("user")("firstName") = firstName
response.cookies("user")("lastName") = lastName
```

If it isn't the IIS settings, and doing a hard coded date test works, then the date  isn't as expected likely.  Here is even an article about that:

[HttpCookie Expires and IIS setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190895/httpcookie-expires-and-iis-setting)

You can also try these things to see what is going on with the date, perhaps its a formatting issue as well, but try these and compare them to your expected results:

```
Year(Now) '' Year in 4 digits
Month(Now) '' Month without leading zero
Day(Now) '' Day of the month without leading zero
DateAdd("d", <numofdays>, Now) ''pretty much what you are doing now
```

with a citation link here :
[ASP formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580185/asp-formatting-date)