# ASP formatting date

Tags: asp-classic

Hello there I'm trying to get a date in ASP to show up in a particular format (yyyymmdd). This is what I've tried so far but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Call Date</b></td>
    <% for i = -6 to 0 %>
        <td align=center>
            <a href="20a.asp?cldate=<% response.write(DateTime.Date()+i.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) %>" target="_blank">X</a>
        </td>
    <% Next %>
</tr>
```

Comment: Classic ASP is not .NET - you need to use VBScript objects and notation. Also - why are you trying to append an `i.ToString()` to the date too? Why are you trying to format the integer?

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the following functions:

```
Year(Now) '' Year in 4 digits
Month(Now) '' Month without leading zero
Day(Now) '' Day of the month without leading zero

DateAdd("d", <numofdays>, Now) '' add a number of days to your date
```

Read more about these (and other date functions) functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp).

If you need to add a leading zero:

```
function addLeadingZero(value)
    addLeadingZero = value
    if value < 10 then
        addLeadingZero = "0" & value
    end if
end function
```

An example of your case would be:

```
Dim today, myDate

today = Now

for i = -6 to 0
    myDate = DateAdd("d", i, today)

    response.write "<a href=""20a.asp?cldate=" & Year(myDate) & addLeadingZero(Month(myDate)) & addLeadingZero(Day(myDate)) & """ target=""_blank"">X</a>"
next
```

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to dig this up, but it might be of help to some people.  Rather than the "If<10 then add leading zero" logic, I often use the right command and always add a leading zero...

```
response.write "<a href=""20a.asp?cldate=" & Year(myDate) & Right("0" & Month(myDate), 2) & right("0" & Day(myDate), 2) & """ target=""_blank"">X</a>"
```

..This way, you don't need a separate function, and it can be done on one line.  I can't speak for the efficiency of it, but it seems logical.

Answer (score 3):

ASP gets the date from the OS not from the Database, a common error, but it is solved by use:

```
<%
' Date dd/mm/yyyy
Session.lcid=2057 '= UK English
%>
```

I hope it helps people.

Answer (score 3):

You can try. 100% tested!

```
   <% 
     mm = Month(now())
     dd = Day(now())
     yy = Year(now())
     IF len(mm) = 1 THEN
       mm = "0" & mm
     END IF
     IF len(dd) = 1 THEN
       dd = "0" & dd
     END IF
     response.write(yy & "/" & mm & "/" & dd) 
  %>
```

Comment: Like I explained in my solution, the Month and Day functions do not provide a leading zero. OP wants leading zeros (yyyymmdd).

Comment: Don't worry You can use the code I just added above. This is 100% working.

Comment: Sure, now you've changed your answer it will work ;). My comment was not meant for you to 'correct' your answer, just to let you know it was not completely what OP wanted. There was nothing 'wrong' with your first answer.

Comment: @Mandeep: 100% working?  I suggest you take a local copy of Now() rather than calling each time as Now() is a _volatile_ function.  If you run your code at the moment Nov rolls over to Dec, then you could end up with Month=Nov and Day = 1 (of Dec) given you 1 Nov instead of 30 Nov or 1 Dec.  This might sound unlikely but [a] it isn't 100% as you claim and [b] this type of coding is much more significant if applied to hours, minutes, seconds and ms.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <%= DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "/" & DatePart("m", Now) & "/" & DatePart("d", Now) %>
```

Also refer

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/22/Date-formatting-in-VBScript

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: This will not get you the formatting OP is looking for. It is missing the leading zero's.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mid(date(), 7,4) & "-" & Mid(date(), 4,2) & "-" & Left(date(), 2)
```