# Classic ASP format date

Tags: asp-classic

I have a date being extracted from the database which is formatted as following

```
11/04/2013
```

Which is

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

I want to convert it in classic asp to the following

```
04/11/2013
```

which is

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might a duplicate of an earlier question. I found a response here: [ASP formatting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580185/asp-formatting-date).

In the example, instead of `Now()` you would use a DateTime representation of your date. In order to get that from a string use [`CDate(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (Click to see the documentation).

In the interests of providing a full example, to get your date you could do something like this:

```
Dim vbDate
vbDate = CDate("11/04/2013")

Response.Write(addLeadingZero(Day(vbDate)) & "/" & addLeadingZero(Month(vbDate)) & "/" & Year(vbDate))

function addLeadingZero(value)
    addLeadingZero = value
    if value < 10 then
        addLeadingZero = "0" & value
    end if
end function
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow too! Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: @lewiguez Don't use that site  as reference/documentation see --> http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Rafael I love that you actually took the time to edit the post to remove it and replace it MSDN :)